# mysql_fetch_assoc to echo linked table results with php

Tags: php, mysql, fetch, associative-array

Using php, I am trying to link results from 3 tables that are connected by a same value. I would then like each dynamic set of related results to repeat as a while loop on the page. This is the result I would like:

artist->

series1->piece1, piece2
series2->piece3, piece4

Artists and series tables share a matched column named 'artist'. Series and piece table have a matched column name 'series'. I know these tables are linked through this same matched value in the database as on another page cascade delete is working.

Currently it only shows the series as an echo repeat loop but with no artist or piece related on either side. Like so: http://www.exhibitjewellery.com/artistindex.php

Whether a mysql_fetch_assoc is the right way, I am not sure. I am confused as to whether the tables are linking correctly at all or if the problem is how I have divided the body section for formatting.  I have a feeling a multidimensional array may help or even nesting the tables but I haven't quite grasped how all the details combine throughout each section of the code. Please help!

PHP above the head:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$query_artistrecordset = "SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY artist ASC";
$artistrecordset = mysql_query($query_artistrecordset, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
$row_artistrecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($artistrecordset);
$totalRows_artistrecordset = mysql_num_rows($artistrecordset);

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$query_seriesrecordset = "SELECT * FROM series, artists WHERE series.artist=artists.artist ORDER BY exhibition ASC";
$seriesrecordset = mysql_query($query_seriesrecordset, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
$resultseries = mysql_query($query_seriesrecordset);
$row_seriesrecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultseries);
$totalRows_seriesrecordset = mysql_num_rows($seriesrecordset);

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$query_piecerecordset = "SELECT * FROM pieces,series WHERE pieces.piece=series.series ORDER BY piece ASC";
$piecerecordset = mysql_query($query_piecerecordset, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
$resultpiece = mysql_query($query_piecerecordset);
$row_piecerecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultpiece);
$totalRows_piecerecordset = mysql_num_rows($piecerecordset);  
?>
```

This is how I have tried to echo it in the body:

```
<div id="serieslist" align="right">
     <?php echo $row_artistrecordset['artist']; ?><br />
     <?php echo $row_artistrecordset['website']; ?><br />
     <?php echo $row_artistrecordset['artist_statement']; ?><br />   
<?php do { ?>
     <?php echo $row_seriesrecordset['series']; ?><br />
     <?php echo $row_seriesrecordset['exhibition']; ?><br />
     <?php echo $row_seriesrecordset['series_statement']; ?><br />
<?php do { ?>
      <?php echo $row_piecerecordset['piece']; ?><br />
      <?php echo $row_piecerecordset['description']; ?><br />
      <?php echo $row_piecerecordset['category']; ?><br />
      <?php echo $row_piecerecordset['dimensions']; ?><br />
      <?php echo $row_piecerecordset['price']; ?><br />
          add to collection button<br />         
  <?php } while ($row_piecerecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultpiece)); ?>  
  <?php } while ($row_seriesrecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultseries)); ?>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($artistrecordset);
mysql_free_result($seriesrecordset);
mysql_free_result($piecerecordset);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this for days!

Comment: First order of business: **don't** use `mysql`. It's deprecated, and has been removed in the most recent version of PHP. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: sure, what do I change to upgrade? do I simply place an 'i' after all 'mysql' phrases?

Comment: Here's the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). `Mysqli` is very similar to `mysql`, but you do need to watch the order and number of parameters

Comment: ok, thankyou. how will this affect what I am trying to achieve? are statements I have made now invalid in msqli?

Comment: You're queries won't change, but the exact syntax of the mysqli functions will differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs I recommend you use object oriented PHP. Keep this on a separate, secure page called db.php, or something:

```
//db.php
<?php
  function db(){
    return new mysqli('replaceWithHostName', 'relaceWithUserName', 'replaceWithPassWord', 'replaceWithDatebaseName');
  }
?>
```

Now for your other page:

```
//other.php
<?php
include('db.php'); $db = db(); $nr = 'No Results Were Found'; $od = '<div>'; $cd = '</div>'; $br = '<br />'; $ar = $sr = $pr = '';
$artistrecordset = $db->query('SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY artist ASC');
if(!$artistrecordset)die($db->error);
if($artistrecordset->num_rows > 0){
  while($row_ar = $artistrecordset->fetch_assoc()){
    $ar .= $od.$row_ar['artist'].$br.$row_ar['website'].$br.$row_ar['artist_statement'].$cd;
  }
  $artistrecordset->free();
}
else){
  die($nr);
}
$seriesrecordset = $db->query('SELECT * FROM series, artists WHERE series.artist=artists.artist ORDER BY exhibition ASC');
if(!$seriesrecordset)die($db->error);
if($seriesrecordset->num_rows > 0){
  while($row_sr = $seriesrecordset->fetch_assoc()){
    $sr .= $od.$row_sr['series'].$br.$row_sr['exhibition'].$br.$row_sr['series_statement'].$cd;
  }
  $seriesrecordset->free();
}
else){
  die($nr);
}
$piecerecordset = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pieces,series WHERE pieces.piece=series.series ORDER BY piece ASC');
if(!$piecerecordset)die($db->error);
if($piecerecordset->num_rows > 0){
  while($row_pr = $piecerecordset->fetch_assoc()){
    $pr .= $od.$row_pr['piece'].$br.$row_pr['description'].$br.$row_pr['category'].$br.$row_pr['dimensions'].$br.$row_pr['price'].$cd;
  }
  $piecerecordset->free();
}
else){
  die($nr);
}
$db->close();
$head = '<html><head></head><body>'; //this could be your other info
echo "$head<div id='serieslist' align='right'>$ar$sr$pr$cd".
"<script type='text/javascript'>/*you should put your JavaScript here*/</script>".
'</body></html>';
?>
```

Really, you should use an external `src` for your JavaScript so it's cached. Sorry, if the format is hard to read. Use the scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

Working from your code, here's a version converted to mysqli, with some of the redundant lines removed. I haven't been able to test this, so a little debugging might be required.

```
<?php
$connectmysql = mysqli_connect("dbhost","dbuser","dbname","dbname") or die("Database error:".mysqli_connect_error);

$query_artistrecordset = "SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY artist ASC";
$artistrecordset = mysqli_query($connectmysql, $query_artistrecordset) or die(mysqli_error);

$query_seriesrecordset = "SELECT * FROM series, artists WHERE series.artist=artists.artist ORDER BY exhibition ASC";
$seriesrecordset = mysqli_query($connectmysql, $query_seriesrecordset ) or die(mysqli_error);

$query_piecerecordset = "SELECT * FROM pieces,series WHERE pieces.piece=series.series ORDER BY piece ASC";
$piecerecordset = mysqli_query($connectmysql, $query_piecerecordset) or die(mysqli_error);

echo "<div id="serieslist" align="right">"

while ($row_artistrecordset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($artistrecordset)) {
     echo $row_artistrecordset['artist'],"<br>";
     echo $row_artistrecordset['website'],"<br>";
     echo $row_artistrecordset['artist_statement'],"<br>";
while ($row_seriesrecordset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seriesrecordset)) {
     echo $row_seriesrecordset['series'],"<br>";
     echo $row_seriesrecordset['exhibition'],"<br>";
     echo $row_seriesrecordset['series_statement'],"<br>";
while ($row_piecerecordset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($piecerecordset)) {  

    echo $row_piecerecordset['piece'],"<br>";
    echo $row_piecerecordset['description'],"<br>";
    echo $row_piecerecordset['category'],"<br>";
    echo $row_piecerecordset['dimensions'],"<br>";
    echo $row_piecerecordset['price'],"<br>";
      echo "add to collection button<br />";    
} // end of pieces
} // end of series
} //end of artists
mysqli_free_result($artistrecordset);
mysqli_free_result($seriesrecordset);
mysqli_free_result($piecerecordset);
echo "</div>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou, that is a great framework for the upgrade solution that I feel confident working from, whilst it doesn't solve the linking problem, its a big help for the other issue!

Comment: this upgrade has totally failed my connection despite editing the original include connection file

Comment: o my. now it is all destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to write while loop for `$row_artistrecordset` as you did also for others, see your code there are only two loops.

Comment: ok, so I am not repeating the artist as only one artist will be displayed per result set on the page. and I thought that I had the while loop for piece and series down the bottom as in previous experiments this seemed to be how the results wrapped as a list but I could be wrong....

Comment: also, why $row_piecerecordset was inside $row_seriesrecordset?

Comment: this was a way for me to have the results of series->piece show in other experiments. I changed it and the artist and piece results on either side of series still does not show

Comment: @Akam That is not an answer, thats just a comment.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am just confused with many people like you, there are many many shorter answer on this site with 50K upvote, but whenever someone don't like an answer says that its a comment, any way thanks for your -v

Comment: @Akam Sorry I didnt mean to offend, but you have to admit that does not attempt to answer the persons question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i just want to help him out I can rewrite the code like you did, but letting people to do the job by themselves is better...

Answer (score 0):

First try this query in something like phpMyAdmin to see if it gets the result you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists a
JOIN series s ON s.artist = a.artist
JOIN pieces p ON p.series = s.series
ORDER BY a.artist;
```

Then process the single result like this.

```
mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$q = "SELECT * FROM artists a 
      JOIN series s ON s.artist = a.artist 
      JOIN pieces p ON p.series = s.series
      ORDER BY a.artist";

$result = mysql_query($q, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo $row['artist'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['website'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['artist_statement'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['series'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['exhibition'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['series_statement'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['piece'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['description'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['category'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['dimensions'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['price'] . '<br />';
    echo ' add to collection button<br />';
}
```

Ok you should also use mysqli or PDO as the mysql extension is now deprecated, but without changing everything and its not a like for like `just add a i` conversion, you could try this as an interim solution.

Comment: thankyou for the mysqli upgrade solution, i have been trying to find a straightforward way to do this for a while! just to confirm, I replace your code with the entirety of what I have already got above the head? or this in addition to?

Comment: the echo solution in the head does not allow me to format the page in html and I have found it difficult to then place the echoes in the body so I can wrap it in a layout. there is also a syntax error on the 'foreach' line of the code